# how do i use the node 'filename' command

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am following this tutorial on how to use APIs. After writing some code, the tutor used the Node.js command `filename` on the terminal in vscode.

I tried the same thing, but somehow it doesnt work it just throws this error:

```
C:\Users\FASF\dev\api>node try.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
throw err;
^

 Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\FASF\dev\api\try.js'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
 at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
 at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: []
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: so don't know if this is an answer per say but i changed the terminal to use git bash and it's working fine. don't know why it doesnt work in cmd

Comment: Can you show your code in the `try.js ` file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the file 'try.js' even exists in the path: 'C:\Users\FASF\dev\api'.
Please check the filename or directory and re-run.